# Notification using jersey 2.8 - To notify to specific group of users

Tags: jersey, server-sent-events

We are using jersey 2.8 for implementing RESTful webservice in our application.

So for the same we are using ServerSentEvent (SSE) to notify the user for occurrence of any event in the server side.

We found that there are 2 ways of implementing the same.
1. Notification.
2. Broadcast.

For both type the registered user gets the notification.

Notification: User registers for a specific event for the same a new thread will be created and the client will be notified in the thread.

Problem using Notification approach:  In case of notification, we have to keep on waiting for the event to occur(by simply polling for occurrence of event in a thread infinitely).

Broadcast: In order get rid infinitely polling for an event we used broadcast. Here, user registers for a specific event, and the event occurs it can be published to the client.

Problem with Broadcast approach: In case if we want to notify specific group of users we are not getting how exactly this should be implemented.

For instance: In case of Facebook notification, person X posts some status, there are following categories of persons,
Y - Who has liked the post.
Z - who has commented on the post.
q - who is friend of X but has neither commented nor liked.

So when person X posts some status update, person Z will comment on it so he will be registered for the event (i.e. if someone else comments on the post then Z will be notified, but Y will not be notified).

How to achieve such kind of notification using jersey 2.8 SSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following way of implementing the same

1. I wrote a wrapper to the broadcaster, which accepts all the requests, it maintains a Map, which contains map of the broadcaster to the respective clients to be notified.

    For example: using the same example in the question, for persons X's post when person Z who comments on the post, then 2 services will be invoked,

   - one will be for posting the comment.
   - other will be for registering for the notification.
     So in the map we will have an entry for `commentId` mapped to the broadcaster. And the user Z will be added to the list of clients to be broadcasted.
2. Whenever any new event occurs, then we will get the broadcaster to which we need to broadcast from the Map, and we broadcast to that broadcaster.

    For example: when somebody else comments on the post, from the map we will get the corresponding broadcaster using the `commentId` and we broadcast the message to the clients.